# Absolutely Centering a table in HTML

Tags: html, css, html-table, center, dreamweaver

I used Dreamweaver to cut an image into different sections; essentially, each piece was "cut" up and stored in a table in HTML. (According to my understanding).

What is the correct way to center this "table" so that the image is in the middle of my web page? (Both Horizontally & Vertically)

Comment: Don't use tables for this purpose. It's hard to answer your question without seeing what you have.

Comment: @Paul: Are you advising against the use of a table-based layout to center the table (I agree)? Or advising against the use of tables for splitting up the image?  And why?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you are cutting it up with tables? More information on your project would be helpful, so we can suggest a better alternative.

Comment: For those of you advising against tables without thinking: http://www.sliceimage.com/howto/split-image-for-html-splitting

Comment: @RobertHarvey - That's about slicing images. 100% acceptable. I'm advising against using a table to handle the layout.

Comment: Essentially, this web page is just going to have an image with links to other websites.

I sliced the image up.

Comment: I put the table in a div with align="center" and it worked; horizontally - however, is there a way to align vertically?

Answer (score 1):

Try using `align="center"` and `valign="middle"` in the table tag